# Change dynamic button text on mouseover by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

how to Change dynamic button text on mouseover by jQuery,

button

```
 <button type="button" id="sendRequest" ><span>Avialable Now</span></button>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sendRequest').hover(function() {
         $(this).find('span').text('Send Request');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('span').text('Avialable Now');
 });
});
```

I want to change text on every dynamacly created button,with above I can change text on only single or first button.

Comment: Give each of the dynamically created button a class name. And use that class name for changing the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your selector from `$('#sendRequest')` To
`$('button')`. This will raise the `event` on the current `button`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').hover(function() {
         $(this).find('span').text('Send Request');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('span').text('Avialable Now');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="sendRequest1" ><span>Avialable Now</span></button>
<button type="button" id="sendRequest2" ><span>Avialable Now</span></button>
```

Comment: @manjunath, you are most welcome.